# COBOL function output as string

Tags: cobol

```
123456*
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. "EVEN-OR-ODD".
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01 Num-1    PIC 9(02).
       02 Answer   PIC XXXX.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
           GOBACK.
       EVEN-OR-ODD.
          IF FUNCTION REM(NUM-1, 2) = 0
              COMPUTE ANSWER =  "Even"
          ELSE
              COMPUTE ANSWER = "Odd"
          END-IF
       END PROGRAM EVEN-OR-ODD.
```

Its a simple even odd function. It should check if number is even return "even" else return "odd"
Can someone explain what's wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So much things a COBOL compiler would have told you...

- `GOBACK` as first statement, so the rest would not be executed
- the program misses a final period and a necessary/reasonable (that depends on the compiler) statement to end the program (`END PROGRAM` is only parsed for the compilation phase) - you likely want to move your `GOBACK.` to the end
- `COMPUTE` does not set anything to alphanumeric, you likely want `MOVE`
- there is no way to know what the program would have done, so possibly want `DISPLAY` instead of `MOVE`
- `NUM-1` is never set and has no initial `VALUE` - so it could theoretically even abend

Comment: lots of things that are wrong with this. thanks (completely new to COBOL)

Comment: You possibly want to try an online compiler with small samples like https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-cobol-online/ - or just get the free GnuCOBOL compiler, possibly check the additional warnings with `-Wall` or even `-Wextra`. You possibly also want to check out the tutorials and docs there like https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/contrib/HEAD/tree/trunk/samples/worldcities/ and the Programmer's Guide https://gnucobol.sourceforge.io/guides.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for that